# Parametric plot gives good graph for x variable range 0 - 10000 but fails to plot for 1 -- 10000

Tags: plotting, graphics

Please explain why pF4 provides a good graph while pF4a, pF4b give nothing ...

All I do is change the range of variable x from 0-10000 to 1-10000

```
pF4 = ParametricPlot[
{Log10[x], (-1 + m^b/(m - n x)^b) /. {b -> 
    0.5} /. {m -> {1}} /. {n -> -0.03}}, {x, 0, 10000}, 
 AspectRatio -> 0.4, AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}, PlotStyle -> {Pink}, 
 PlotPoints -> 500]

 pF4a = ParametricPlot[
 {Log10[x], (-1 + m^b/(m - n x)^b) /. {b -> 
    0.5} /. {m -> {1}} /. {n -> -0.03}}, {x, 0.0, 10000}, 
 AspectRatio -> 0.4, AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}, PlotStyle -> {Pink}, 
 PlotPoints -> 500]

 pF4b = ParametricPlot[
 {Log10[x], (-1 + m^b/(m - n x)^b) /. {b -> 
    0.5} /. {m -> {1}} /. {n -> -0.03}}, {x, 1, 10000}, 
 AspectRatio -> 0.4, AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}, PlotStyle -> {Pink}, 
 PlotPoints -> 500]
```

Comment: Works if you change `{m -> {1}}` to `{m -> 1}`; however, I would shorten the replacements to `/. {b -> 0.5, m -> 1, n -> -0.03}`

Comment: So it does. Thank you so much. The infinite mysteries of M.